I get Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
I'm experiencing a couple of issues with configuring and using OpenAI in a Firebase function.
When trying to access the OpenAI API key in the openaiConfig.ts file, I get the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')

Here's the relevant part of the code:
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const openaiApiKey = functions.config().openai.key;

export const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: openaiApiKey,
});

I set the environment variable using the command:
firebase functions:config:set openai.key="MY_KEY"

Additional Information:
The functions execute normally when deployed to the cloud.
The issue occurs only when running locally with the command:
firebase emulators:start

Version:
firebase-admin: "^12.1.0",
firebase-functions: "^5.0.0",
openai: "^4.56.0"

When testing locally, use the Firebase Functions emulator. Make sure to set the environment configuration for the emulator as well:
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json

This command creates a .runtimeconfig.json file in your functions directory, which the emulator will use.
